# Dropping invalid columns FutureWarning

Tags: python, pandas

```
# Select days that are sunny: sunny
sunny = df_clean.loc[df_clean['sky_condition']=='CLR']

# Select days that are overcast: overcast
overcast = df_clean.loc[df_clean['sky_condition'].str.contains('OVC')]

# Resample sunny and overcast, aggregating by maximum daily temperature
sunny_daily_max = sunny.resample('D').max()
overcast_daily_max = overcast.resample('D').max()

# Print the difference between the mean of sunny_daily_max and overcast_daily_max
print(sunny_daily_max.mean() - overcast_daily_max.mean())


/tmp/ipykernel_1065/1054523508.py:9: FutureWarning: Dropping invalid columns in 
DataFrameGroupBy.max is deprecated. In a future version, a TypeError will be raised. Before 
calling .max, select only columns which should be valid for the function.
overcast_daily_max = overcast.resample('D').max()
/tmp/ipykernel_1065/1054523508.py:12: FutureWarning: Dropping of nuisance columns in DataFrame 
reductions (with 'numeric_only=None') is deprecated; in a future version this will raise 
TypeError.  Select only valid columns before calling the reduction.
  print(sunny_daily_max.mean() - overcast_daily_max.mean())
```

I'm making manipulations with my dataframe and getting this warning. Can i somehow get rid of this warning?

Answer (score 22):

You have some columns in your dataframes are not numeric columns. It is invalid to use `mean()` or `max()` for these columns. To remove these warnings, as suggested by the warning message, you should use `numeric_only` attribute to apply `max` and `mean()`  for numeric columns only.

You can try this:

```
sunny_daily_max = sunny.resample('D').max(numeric_only=True)

sunny_daily_max.mean(numeric_only=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just mention **numeric_only=True** inside the braces of mean, max, sum, etc.
Earlier, this was set default as True but now the default would be False.